# Blank 'home' screen on main site page

Tags: bug

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions

I've selected the 'newest' tab and was able to access and answer a question just now, but the general screen with all questions has suddenly gone blank.
I've just joined the site yesterday and was able to view all questions on the screen then. I don't think I've accidentally clicked/selected anything to make it like this. 
I've also closed down/re-opened the site/page.

Comment: This is hopefully being looked into, but I can confirm that this is an issue on Stack Exchange's end and not yours.

Comment: Thanks for that, I get a bit worried sometimes, because my laptop slows right down at times to the point of freezing.

Comment: This has happened to me three or four times on different occasions in the last two months. It should go away all by itself after a minute.

Comment: [Noted in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7850832#7850832).  This seemed to last longer than normal this time around.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a known bug, but nobody seems to be particularly concerned about it, because it usually goes away after a few minutes.

See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161568/there-are-no-questions-with-an-active-bounty-at-the-moment-what-to-do/161573) or [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165212/strange-behavior-on-academia-se-meta) on the main Meta site.